# Systemd service working on one server but not on the other

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, systemd, python

My service looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run Forever

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/elbrus/perp
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'python3 perpetual.py'
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For some reason I keep getting the following error:

```
perpetual.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: No such file or directory
systemd[41116]: perpetual.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /bin/bash: No such file or directory
systemd[1]: perpetual.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
systemd[1]: perpetual.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This although the folder 100% exists and my permissions look like this:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root             root  931
```

It has been driving me completely crazy as this very same systemd service is running on multiple other servers. Just this one from DigitalOcean I can not get to work.

Comment: Can you replace your `ls` output with the complete output of `ls -ld /home/elbrus/perp`? That will just confirm that the path exists on the failing server.

Comment: `(base) root@perpetual-api:/home/elbrus/perp# ls -ld /home/elbrus/perp
                                                                                                                                drwxr-xr-x 2 elbrus elbrus 4096 Jun 11 13:35 /home/elbrus/perp`

Comment: Can you show relevant bits inside `perpetual.py` if any ? Also to what directory/folder does the  `-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  931` applies ? I would have guessed `/home/elbrus/perp` but its permission does not match what you announced....  so just to make sure.

Comment: It applies to the perpetual.service file.                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                        This is inside of the /home/elbrus/perp folder:                                                                  `-rw-rw-r-- 1 elbrus elbrus   679 Jun 11 01:04 .env
-rwxrwxr-x 1 elbrus elbrus 17857 Jun 11 21:26 perpetual.py`. Sorry for the formatting.